# ¿Qué diferencia hay al momento de instanciar un array con los "[]" antes o después del nombre de la variable?

Tags: java, array

Ejecuté el programa con estas 2 formas diferentes de instanciar un *array* y obtengo el mismo resultado (Se obtiene el resultado deseado), el arreglo debe contener objetos de tipo *Vehiculo*, mi duda es, si definirlos de estas dos maneras esta bien o que diferencia hay.

Solo veo que la diferencia esta en que:

En la forma 1ra pongo `[]` luego del tipo de dato que almacenara el array que en este caso es "*Vehiculo*":

```
Vehiculo[] ArrayVehiculos=new Vehiculo[Numero]
```

Y la 2da forma los `[]` están después del nombre del array:

```
Vehiculo ArrayVehiculos[]=new Vehiculo[Numero];
```

¿Qué diferencia hay al momento de definir de estas 2 maneras un arreglo, es solo el orden?

Comment: No hay ninguna diferencia, ambas son validas.

Answer (score 0):

Como se explica en tu el [tutorial de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), ambas maneras son correctas, aunque se da preferencia a que los brackets vayan antes del nombre de la variable, esto por convención:

**Primera forma:**

```java
// best way to declare an array
float[] anArrayOfFloats;
```

**Segunda Forma:**

```java
// this form is discouraged
float anArrayOfFloats[];
```

> However, convention discourages this form; the brackets identify the array type and should appear with the type designation
>
> ---
>
> Sin embargo, la convención desalienta esta forma; los corchetes identifican el tipo de matriz y deben aparecer con la designación del tipo.